# Error with code: Segmentation Fault, Core dumped

Tags: c

I am having an issue with the output of my code, which is trying to return an array backwards in c using pointers. Do you guys have any solutions to the error I am getting?

Sample input:

```
    Please enter the array size: 3
    Please enter 3 elements:
    4, 5, 7
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
        int size, i;
        int *pointer;
        int arr[size];
        printf("Please enter the array size: ");
        scanf("%d/n", &size);
        pointer = &arr[0];
        printf("Please enter %d elements: \n", size);
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
                scanf("%d", arr[i]);
                pointer++;
        }
        pointer = &arr[size - 1];

        printf("The reversed array is \n");
        for(i = size; i > 0; i--){
                printf("%d", arr[i]);
                pointer--;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the whole line (or partial, but that's more advanced stuff) with `fgets()` then loop with `strtol()` to parse it.

Comment: @ksuk333 You can not take "all integers" in a single line.:)

Comment: @pmg can you show me how in a for loop? Sorry I am still learning C.

Comment: You can take integers in a single line. The scanf does not care what type of whitespace separates them, or what loop there is. For example `for(int i=0; i<3; i++) scanf("%d", %array[i]);` does not care at all whether the inputs are separated by newlines or spaces.

Comment: I expect your teacher expects a `scanf()` solution ... but the thing is: `scanf()` was not designed for user input. Learning to use it for user input is counter-productive.

Comment: @ksuk333 If you type `[c] strtol in a loop` into the search box at the top of the page, the top hit is an answer that shows you how to use `strtol` in a loop.

Comment: @pmg `scanf()` was not designed for user input? :)

Comment: @DavidRanieri ... no, it was designed for *formatted* input (hence the `f` suffix). User input is anything but formatted.

Comment: Typo in my earlier [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721976/how-to-create-a-for-loop-in-c-that-takes-in-all-integers-in-a-single-line#comment130181760_73721976) sorry: use `&array[i]` not `%array[i]`.

Comment: `scanf()` was not designed for line-oriented user input. If you put `scanf` in a loop, it won't know when to stop, because it treats the newline character just like any other whitespace character.

Comment: It basically has to take in whatever integers the line has. So if it has 10 integers on the line, then it has to print all 10 out.

Comment: @WeatherVane So I use a for loop and add it to an array? I tried it here but it said the N was an error. int main() {
    int arr[N];

    printf("Please enter %d numbers:\n", N);
    for(int i=1; i <= N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i-1]);
    }

    for(int i=1; i <= N; i++){
        printf("%d\n", arr[i-1]);
    }

    return 0;
}

Comment: Please post your [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by editing the question. Note: you are creating confusion with the iteration. Get used to `0` as a starting point.

Comment: @ksuk333 If you know that the user is supposed to type 3 numbers on a line, then `#define N 3` will work. If you don't know in advance how many numbers the user is going to type, then the code you've shown in your comment is not the right approach.

Comment: That's too strong, @pmg.  The formatting for which `scanf` and friends is intended is first and foremost formatting as *text*, which is exactly the form of typical user input.  And `scanf()`'s design makes concessions specifically for the purpose, relative to, say, Fortran formatted I/O.  It has been used for interactive user input for as long as it has existed.  `scanf()` certainly has its deficiencies in this area, but I do not accept "not designed for user input".

Comment: Ok @JohnBollinger, I accept the criticism. Let's say I meant "`scanf()` has a few shortcomings, but works wiell enough in toy/learning programs; learning other ways to deal with input is a good idea"

Comment: With *that*, I heartily agree.

Answer (score 2):

The task is not simple for beginners like you and me.

As I have understood the user can enter any number of integers in one line and all entered integers in the line must be outputted like

```
You entered 2
```

In this case neither array nor character array nor integer array will help. And in fact you need not to define an array if you want only to output numbers stored in the input buffer.

In this case you can just use the standard function `getchar`. Using the function in a loop you can read all numbers placed by the user in one line in the I/O buffer.

Here is a sample program. It is a little complicated because I allow the user to enter sign symbols.

There is no check in the program whether the user entered not a digit or a sign. You can develop the program further. The program demonstrates an approach to solve the task.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    printf( "Enter a seria of integer numbers in one line: " );

    int c;
    int sign = 0;
    int num = 0;
    do
    {
        c = getchar();

        if (c == EOF || c == '\n' )
        {
            if (sign)
            {
                printf( "You entered %d\n", num );
            }
        }
        else if (isblank( ( unsigned char )c ))
        {
            if (sign)
            {
                printf( "You entered %d\n", num );
                sign = 0;
                num = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c == '-' || c == '+')
            {
                if (sign)
                {
                    printf( "You entered %d\n", num );
                    num = 0;
                }
                sign = c == '-' ? -1 : 1;
            }
            else if (isdigit( ( unsigned char )c ))
            {
                c -= '0';

                if (sign == 0) sign = 1;

                if (sign == 1)
                {
                    num = Base * num + c;
                }
                else
                {
                    num = Base * num - c;
                }
            }
        }
    } while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
}
```

The program output might look for example like

```
Enter a seria of integer numbers in one line: 1 -1 +12-12+13 +14 -15
You entered 1
You entered -1
You entered 12
You entered -12
You entered 13
You entered 14
You entered -15
```

If you want to enter several lines of numbers and output numbers that are present in each line then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    const int Base = 10;
    size_t i = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf( "Enter a seria of integer numbers in one line (or press just Enter to exit): " );

        int c = getchar();

        if (c == EOF || c == '\n') break;

        ungetc( c, stdin );

        printf( "Line %zu contains the following numbers:\n", i++ );

        int sign = 0;
        int num = 0;
        do
        {
            c = getchar();

            if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
            {
                if (sign)
                {
                    printf( "You entered %d\n", num );
                }
            }
            else if (isblank( ( unsigned char )c ))
            {
                if (sign)
                {
                    printf( "You entered %d\n", num );
                    sign = 0;
                    num = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (c == '-' || c == '+')
                {
                    if (sign)
                    {
                        printf( "You entered %d\n", num );
                        num = 0;
                    }
                    sign = c == '-' ? -1 : 1;
                }
                else if (isdigit( ( unsigned char )c ))
                {
                    c -= '0';

                    if (sign == 0) sign = 1;

                    if (sign == 1)
                    {
                        num = Base * num + c;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        num = Base * num - c;
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (c != EOF && c != '\n');

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output might look for example like

```
Enter a seria of integer numbers in one line (or press just Enter to exit): 1 -2 3 +4
Line 0 contains the following numbers:
You entered 1
You entered -2
You entered 3
You entered 4

Enter a seria of integer numbers in one line (or press just Enter to exit): 11-12 13+14
Line 1 contains the following numbers:
You entered 11
You entered -12
You entered 13
You entered 14

Enter a seria of integer numbers in one line (or press just Enter to exit):
```

As the program just outputs entered numbers then actually there is no need to build an object of the type int like

```
num = Base * num + c;
```

You could just output adjacent digits in a line.

Comment: So Vlad, you're a beginner too? Could have fooled me ;)

Comment: @anastaciu I am a beginner. Nobody suggests me a job because I know too little.

Comment: Sheesh, if that's the case I'm well on my way to unemployment too. It appears that python is where te money is these days. Don't like it at all.

Comment: @anastaciu When you are an unemployed reading books on IT is not very effective. You have no practice. And you're not disciplined

Comment: @VladfromMoscow what if the user used the enter key as well to add integers. Could you alter the code to show that?

Comment: @ksuk333 If the user presses the enter key then it means that he has entered a line of numbers. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I mean that the integers dont have to be on just one line

Comment: @ksuk333 In this case you need one more outer loop and a condition that determines whether the user stopped the input. For example if the user enters an empty string.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow could you edit your code to show me please? that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ksuk333 I can do it tomorrow because it is too late now in Moscow.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
int array[100];
int n;

scanf("%d", &n);

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("You entered %d \n", array[i]);
}
```

We use the array to get all of the values, and just print them out at the end.

In C and C++ it does not matter if the values are separated by space or a newline, so you can get every integer in a single line if separated by spaces.

```
output


3
1 2 3
You entered 1 
You entered 2 
You entered 3
```

Comment: You have, of course, required the user to first specify how many numbers they intend to type. That's not the same as just getting all of the numbers the user enters on a single line.

Comment: Of course, yes, its definitely not the same, in that case you can either get the entire line and parse it, or keep scanning input until you get a newline or "\n".

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` can be used to read a line.
`strtol` can parse integers and report overflow and invalid input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int parselint ( char *line, int *value, char **end) {
    long int number = 0;

        errno = 0;
        number = strtol ( line, end, 10);
        if ( *end == line) {// nothing was parsed. no digits
            size_t span = strcspn ( *end, "-+0123456789"); // characters to next int
            if ( ! span) {
                span = 1;
            }
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem parsing: %.*s\n", (int)span, line);
            *end += span; // advance pointer to next int
            return 0;// return failure
        }
        if ( ( errno == ERANGE && ( number == LONG_MAX || number == LONG_MIN))
        || ( errno != 0 && number == 0)) {// parsing error from strtol
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem %.*s", (int)(*end - line), line);
            perror ( " ");
            return 0;
        }
        if ( number > INT_MAX || number < INT_MIN) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem %.*s ", (int)(*end - line), line);
            fprintf ( stderr, "out of int range\n");
            return 0;
        }
        *value = number;//assign number to pointer

    return 1;//success
}

int main ( void) {
    char line[4096] = "";
    char *parse = line;
    int number = 0;

    fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin);
    line[strcspn ( line, "\r\n")] = 0; // remove newline

    while ( *parse) {
        if ( 1 == parselint ( parse, &number, &parse)) {
            printf ( "you entered %d\n", number);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C makes this very easy, but you need to leverage some library functions. At the most simple:

- use `fgets()` and `strpbrk()` to obtain and verify a line of text
- use `strtok()` and `strtol()` to parse and verify integer values.

What you do with those values is up to you. Following your example prompt, let’s just print them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int error( const char * message, const char * value )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "%s%s\n", message, value );
  return 1;
}

int main()
{
  printf( "Input: " );

  // Get all input on a single line
  char text[1000];
  fgets( text, sizeof(text), stdin );

  // Verify that the entire line of input was obtained
  char * nl = strpbrk( text, "\r\n" );
  if (!nl) return error( "Line too long!", "" );
  *nl = '\0';
  
  puts( "Output:" );
  
  // For each whitespace-delimited (spaces, tabs) token in the line:
  for (char * token = strtok( text, " \t" );  token;  token = strtok( NULL, " \t" ))
  {
    // Attempt to convert it to an integer
    char * nok;
    int n = strtol( token, &nok, 10 );
    if (*nok) return error( "Invalid integer value: ", token );
    
    // Success!
    printf( "You entered %d\n", n );
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Notice also how it is OK to create a little helper function (`error()`). You can make helpers as complex or simple as you *need*. For this helper, all we need was to complain with one or two strings and return an “error happened” exit code that `main()` can pass right to the shell.

Comment: `for(char *tok=text; (tok=strtok(tok, " \t")) != NULL; tok = NULL )` improved usage of `strtok( )`.. No charge... `:-)`

Comment: Alas, I disagree. It’s flaggy and harder to read. I much prefer to just make the separators string a constant value somewhere, which is where the flagginess should be anyway... (Though, I admit I have done it that way too...)

Comment: Yes I am taking offense. "harder to read"? The setup ("statement1") is simpler, the advance ("statement 3") is simpler, and the conditional follows the standard idiom of `(c = getchar()) != EOF`... If it is novel to you, that does not mean it is "flaggy and harder to read" than what you've been accustomed to. (The separators can be defined elsewhere... or not... makes no difference, really...)

Comment: Well, stop taking offense, please. I stated my opinion, which differs from your stated opinion. There is no One True Way here, and we can both be happy. :O)

Comment: `for( int c = fgetc( fp ); c != EOF; c = fgetc( fp ) ) {` If I saw that in code, I'd fire the employee who wrote it... Just sayin'...